# Recommendations for a GUI library?

Tags: c++, winforms, user-interface

I recently ditched C# for C++ because I enjoy coding in it much more.

However, I really do miss Windows Forms and how simple it was to create windows, buttons, etc.

Are there any good C++ libraries out there similar to .NET windows forms? I CAN use C++/CLI, but it bugs me that there isn't any intellisense in Visual Studio!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336688/looking-for-an-application-gui-library-for-c?rq=1 and others

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gui toolkits, which should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584734/gui-toolkits-which-should-i-use)

Comment: Are you asking purely about a GUI library or a GUI library plus form designer? You mention how simple it was creating windows, buttons, etc which you'd not normally do directly with the library.

Comment: @tinman A form designer would be nice, but just a GUI library would suffice! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).  I find that the signals and slots is a fairly simple concept to pick up if you're used to Windows Forms.

Comment: I'd second this! Qt may not be the best for 'professional' applications (although it was pretty widely used at one point in programs like Skype), but it's a great library to help in getting used to GUI programming in C++ in-general. You may also want to look into Qt Creator; it's a pretty decent IDE by itself, and can get you started with its drag-and-drop editor (although it starts to become more trouble than it's worth past the learning phase IMO)

Comment: @AlexFZ Qt is used by a lot of "professional" applications, as well...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you Qt. It has got great documentation and it is really simple to learn and use. Also it has huge abilities. For example Google Earth was using it :) [Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/index.html) some more informations.

Answer (score 1):

Try [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). It compiles on *many* differnt plattforms and in contrast to Qt features native widgets, significantly imporving usability.